# T-SQL full join query that returns only null values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to make m query to where it returns only the null values but instead it returns all values. I am new to T-SQL and am not sure how to search this problem so I have included what I tried. My below code just returns the column headers. How can I change my query to retrieve only null values?

```
SELECT distinct o.ORDER_NUMBER, d.Drop
FROM [****\sqlexpress].FRESH.dbo.Order o
FULL OUTER JOIN
[****\sqlexpress].*****.dbo.Drop d
ON o.ORDER_NUMBER = d.OrderNumber
WHERE d.Drop = null
Order by o.ORDER_NUMBER
```

Comment: Try `WHERE d.Drop IS null`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `WHERE d.Drop IS NULL` instead of `d.Drop = NULL`.